# Delayed choice double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-eraser

I want to be certain, was there an experiment ever performed, like, where if we do not look at the screen and then the  detector at the double slit destroyed(which path information is lost). And then the screen is observed. Does the wave function collapses? Thanks.

Comment: The english here needs work.

Comment: The result on the screen does not depend on anyone looking at it. What changes the result is the interaction with the detectors, but not our knowledge if it.